PyQt6 TreeWidget not importing colors from ui fil
I am trying to set the individual colors of each line in a QtreeWidget, I have tried setting them manually as I fill the treeView with .setForeground(col, QBrush(QColor(R, G, B, a))) and without the alpha value. I have also tried filling out the treeView in PyQT6 Designer, and it looks fine in the designer, but when I export the .ui file and import it, the colors don't show up (I have even checked the .ui XML data, and I can see the color property in the file), is this an issue with QtreeWidget, or am I doing something wrong?
import sys
from PyQt6.uic import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *

class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        loadUi("Test.ui", self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)#[])
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>480</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QTreeWidget" name="treeWidget">
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>1</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Test1</string>
       </property>
       <property name="foreground">
        <brush brushstyle="NoBrush">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Test2</string>
       </property>
       <property name="foreground">
        <brush brushstyle="NoBrush">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>170</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Test3</string>
       </property>
       <property name="foreground">
        <brush brushstyle="NoBrush">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>85</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </property>
      </item>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>640</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>


What OS and Qt (not PyQt) version? Note that if you're on Windows 11 and Qt 6.7, it's a known bug.

Yes, I am, do you know if it will work on a different version?

Currently, it will work as expected only up to 6.6.3. It will be fixed as soon as Qt>=6.7.3 will be released. A related question has been recently posted, I wrote a detailed answer for possible solutions there: Unable to alter the text color within a QTableWidget (it's for QTableWidget while you're using QTreeWidget, but that's irrelevant, since they are both based on the same concepts). For future reference, always consider to add proper environment details and their versions (OS, interpreter, libraries, etc.). Also, Designer is part of Qt, not PyQt.
